# Copy file from AWS S3 bucket to Google cloud storage bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to copy file from AWS S3 bucket to Google Storage bucket. I am trying to implement with python api. Please help me if anyone done this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to do this.
You can also use the [GCS Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/).